# Jinja add automatic indentation

Tags: ansible, jinja2

In ansible I use a template written in jinja2,
I have an inner for loop which automatically adds space to my config file, which i do not want to.

```
  stick store-response payload_lv(43,1) if serverhello

  option ssl-hello-chk

      {% set count = 1 %}
      {% for ip in sv.ips %}
      server server{{ count }} {{ ip }}:443 check
      {% set count = count + 1 %}
      {% endfor %}
```

Result is

```
  stick store-response payload_lv(43,1) if serverhello

  option ssl-hello-chk

    server server1 10.2.0.16:443 check
    server server2 10.2.0.20:443 check
```

Comment: You shared your story and your result. Do you have any question? And btw google "Jinja2 whitespace control" before you make up your mind what the question is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this line at the top of your template, will preserve the indentation

```
#jinja2: trim_blocks: True, lstrip_blocks: True
```